# How to express and enforce that a class has 2 modes of operation, each having some valid and invalid methods

Tags: python, mypy

I'm very new to type checking in Python.  I'd like to find a way to use it to check for this common situation:

1. class (e.g. my DbQuery class) is instantiated, is in some uninitialized state. e.g. I'm a db query-er but I havent connected to a db yet. You could say (abstractly) the instance is of type 'Unconnected Db Query Connector'
2. user calls .connect() which sets the class instance to connected. Can now think of this class instance as belong to a new category (protocol?). You could say the instance is of type 'Connected DB Query Connector' now...
3. user calls .query(), etc. uses the class.  The query method is annotated to express that self in this case must be a 'Connected DB Query Connector'

In an incorrect usage, which I would like to detect automatically: the user instantiates the db connector and then calls query() without calling connect first.

Is there a representation for this with annotations?  Can I express that the connect() method has caused 'self' to join a new type? or is that the right way to do it?

Is there some other standard mechanism for expressing this and detecting it in Python or mypy?

I might be able to see how this could be expressed with inheritance maybe... I'm not sure

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here's what I wish I could do:

```py
from typing import Union, Optional, NewType, Protocol, cast


class Connector:
    def __init__(self, host: str) -> None:
        self.host = host

    def run(self, sql: str) -> str:
        return f"I ran {sql} on {self.host}"


# This is a version of class 'A' where conn is None and you can't call query()
class NoQuery(Protocol):
    conn: None


# This is a version of class 'A' where conn is initialized. You can query, but you cant call connect()
class CanQuery(Protocol):
    conn: Connector


# This class starts its life as a NoQuery. Should switch personality when connect() is called
class A(NoQuery):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.conn = None

    def query(self: CanQuery, sql: str) -> str:
        return self.conn.run(sql)

    def connect(self: NoQuery, host: str):
        # Attempting to change from 'NoQuery' to 'CanQuery' like this
        # mypy complains: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "CanQuery", variable has type "NoQuery")
        self = cast(CanQuery, self)
        self.conn = Connector(host)


a = A()
a.connect('host.domain')
print(a.query('SELECT field FROM table'))


b = A()
# mypy should help me spot this. I'm trying to query an unconnected host. self.conn is None
print(b.query('SELECT oops'))
```

For me, this is a common scenario (an object that has a few distinct and very meaningful modes of operation).  Is there no way to express this in mypy?

Comment: why don't you just create specific types for this? I don't think the type system supports what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, willing to admit that 2 step initialization is a 'code smell' anyway. But, I still think it might useful in some cases to be able to annotate multiple distinct personalities for the same object "class" ....

Comment: Learned: this concept is perhaps called "refinement types". Adding it to mypy is discussed and rejected here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/560. In addition to needing refinement types, I also need a way to show that calling a function changes the type of one or more of the params. I have no idea... That's more of a contract annotation I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to hack something together by making your `A` class a generic type, (ab)using Literal enums, and annotating the self parameter, but frankly I don't think that's a good idea.

Mypy in general assumes that calling a method won't change the type of a method, and circumventing that is probably not possible without resorting that gross hacks and a bunch of casts or `# type: ignore`s.

Instead, the standard convention is to use two classes -- a "connection" object and a "query" object -- along with context managers. This, as a side benefit, would also let you ensure your connections are always closed once you're done using them.

For example:

```py
from typing import Union, Optional, Iterator
from contextlib import contextmanager


class RawConnector:
    def __init__(self, host: str) -> None:
        self.host = host

    def run(self, sql: str) -> str:
        return f"I ran {sql} on {self.host}"

    def close(self) -> None:
        print("Closing connection!")


class Database:
    def __init__(self, host: str) -> None:
        self.host = host

    @contextmanager
    def connect(self) -> Iterator[Connection]:
        conn = RawConnector(self.host)
        yield Connection(conn)
        conn.close()


class Connection:
    def __init__(self, conn: RawConnector) -> None:
        self.conn = conn

    def query(self, sql: str) -> str:
        return self.conn.run(sql)

db = Database("my-host")
with db.connect() as conn:
    conn.query("some sql")
```

If you really want to combine these two new classes into one, you can by (ab)using literal types, generics, and self annotations and by keeping within the constraint that you can only ever *return* instances with new personalities.

For example:

```
# If you are using Python 3.8+, you can import 'Literal' directly from
# typing. But if you need to support older Pythons, you'll need to
# pip-install typing_extensions and import from there.
from typing import Union, Optional, Iterator, TypeVar, Generic, cast
from typing_extensions import Literal
from contextlib import contextmanager
from enum import Enum


class RawConnector:
    def __init__(self, host: str) -> None:
        self.host = host

    def run(self, sql: str) -> str:
        return f"I ran {sql} on {self.host}"

    def close(self) -> None:
        print("Closing connection!")

class State(Enum):
    Unconnected = 0
    Connected = 1

# Type aliases here for readability. We use an enum and Literal
# types mostly so we can give each of our states a nice name. We
# could have also created an empty 'State' class and created an
# 'Unconnected' and 'Connected' subclasses: all that matters is we
# have one distinct type per state/per "personality".
Unconnected = Literal[State.Unconnected]
Connected = Literal[State.Connected]

T = TypeVar('T', bound=State)

class Connection(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self: Connection[Unconnected]) -> None:
        self.conn: Optional[RawConnector] = None

    def connect(self: Connection[Unconnected], host: str) -> Connection[Connected]:
        self.conn = RawConnector(host)
        # Important! We *return* the new type!
        return cast(Connection[Connected], self)

    def query(self: Connection[Connected], sql: str) -> str:
        assert self.conn is not None
        return self.conn.run(sql)


c1 = Connection()
c2 = c1.connect("foo")
c2.query("some-sql")

# Does not type check, since types of c1 and c2 do not match declared self types
c1.query("bad")
c2.connect("bad")
```

Basically, it becomes possible to make a type act more or less as a state machine as long as we stick with *returning* new instances (even if at runtime, we always return just 'self').

With a little more cleverness/a few more compromises, you might even be able to get rid of the cast whenever you transition from one state to another.

But tbh, I consider this sort of trick to be overkill/probably inappropriate for what you seem to be trying to do. I would personally recommend the two classes + contextmanager approach.

Comment: This is nice. I completely agree that a context manager, more of a factory pattern or something is really the right way to do this. But that breaks my fake example. :)  Your solution there is good. I tried it and it works as expected. I'll have to figure out how the bound thing works.   I guess you're still missing the critical component of providing an annotation that indicates that a function will receive (self) args of type X and the object will be of type Y at the end of the function.  I take it this cannot be done.  I was hoping to annot with 0 code changes.  Thanks for the response!